# QGIS 2.8.1 running error

Tags: qgis, error

I am using QGIS 2.8.1-Wein 32bit version.  When running QGIS, it does not open. After displaying like below the picture, nothing happens. If you can solve this problem, please give me a solution.

I also tried re-installation.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps a plugin is corrupted. Go to the plugins folder and delete all of them

Comment: Did you have QGIS < 2.8 installed before installing this? Which installer did you use? the QGIS.org download, OSGEO or other means? Do you have a 64bit O.S.? Are you using Linux? if so what flavor? Do you have 64bit GDAL installed?